# Ruby - Iterate over parsed json with no hash name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

So I'm trying to do some work with JIRA's REST API to get our upcoming releases schedule. From their API I can get returned JSON as seen below:

```
[{
"self": "https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/version/15701",
"id": "15701",
"description": "First release",
"name": "1.4.3",
"archived": false,
"released": true,
"releaseDate": "2013-02-28",
"userReleaseDate": "28/Feb/13",
"projectId": 10005
},
{
"self": "https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/version/15685",
"id": "15685",
"description": "Second release",
"name": "1.4.5",
"archived": false,
"released": true,
"releaseDate": "2013-03-11",
"userReleaseDate": "11/Mar/13",
"projectId": 10005
}
]
```

So I've looked over other answers on the site and I can't quite figure out when I have a block that doesn't have an identifier. For example this question, reddit's api names each json object while JIRA does not. [Ruby - iterate over parsed JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132623/ruby-iterate-over-parsed-json)

I've tried something along the lines of

```
json[''].each do |release|
    puts release['description']
end
```

But that's where I'm a bit lost. I put [''] because there is no key to go off there. I'm quite new to JSON so my terminology might be way off here too...

Comment: What about `json.each do |release|`?

Comment: Swear I tried that but that seems to work. Blah well thanks for the help though! I feel stupid haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be given an `Array` object when you parse that JSON string.

If you write the following code:

```
json.each do |release|
  puts release['self']
end
```

You should see this output:

```
https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/version/15685
https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/version/15701
```